# Is there a way to fill a column of a dataframe with values from a list, grouped by each individual item - Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset that I would like to explore but it is not structured very well. The original excel had the Region and Variety of grape in the one column, the Region was indicated as the heading for the rows beneath by being in bold. When I loaded it into Python you can't tell which rows were regions or grape varieties.

Ideally I want to have those two columns separated so my ideal dataframe looks like table 2.

What I have done so far is add a 'is_region" column and put "Yes" for values in the 'Region/variety' column that match my list of regions.

```
grapeyield_df = pd.read_excel (r'Regional varietal area, production and price data, 1999 to 2013.xlsx', 'Yield_since2001_tab',skiprows=[0])

regions = ['Adelaide Hills','Adelaide Plains','Alpine Valleys','Alpine Valleys/Beechworth','Australian Capital Territory','Barossa -other','Barossa Valley']

grapeyield_df["is_region"] = np.where(grapeyield_df["Region/Variety"].isin(regions), "Yes", "No")
```

Table 1:

| Region/Variety | 2011 | is_region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adelaide Hills | 3452 | Yes |
| Chardonnay | 26357 | No |
| Pinot Grigio | 7876 | No |
| Barossa Valley | 7368 | Yes |

Table 2:

| Region | Variety | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adelaide Hills | Chardonnay | 26357 |
| Adelaide Hills | Pinot Grigio | 7876 |
| Barossa Valley | Chardonnay | 8787 |

Comment: What happened to the 3452 cell at [0,1] in Table1?

Comment: Can you give a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: The values do not matter to me at this moment.  The table I have shown is a simplified version of the actual table, the only column of interest here is Region/Variety, I'm not sure what more you would need to reproduce this example @Coyote. If you need to view the raw data you can download it from here https://universityofadelaide.app.box.com/s/c1v2vv2zdug5pk2nmntxzg7tmw3z1v13/file/714492389420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
df["Region"] = df["Region/Variety"].where(df["Region/Variety"].isin(regions)).ffill()
df = (
    df[df["Region/Variety"] != df["Region"]]
    .reset_index().rename(columns={"Region/Variety": "Variety"})
)[["Region", "Variety", "2011"]]
```

The first step is adding a `"Region"` column (using `.where` and `.ffill`). The second takes those parts of `df` that don't belong to the region-rows, resets the index, renames the `"Region\Variety"`-column into `"Variety"`, and selects the columns in the requested order.

Result for

```
df:
   Region/Variety   2011
0  Adelaide Hills   3452
1      Chardonnay  26357
2    Pinot Grigio   7876
3  Barossa Valley   7368
4      Chardonnay   8787
```

is

```
           Region       Variety   2011
0  Adelaide Hills    Chardonnay  26357
1  Adelaide Hills  Pinot Grigio   7876
2  Barossa Valley    Chardonnay   8787
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive way of doing it would use pandas [`ffill`-method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
# Split ambiguous column.
df['region'] = df['Region/Variety'].copy()
df['variety'] = df['Region/Variety'].copy()
df = df.drop('Region/Variety', axis=1)

# Shadow invalid regions.
idx_regions = df['region'].isin(regions)
df.loc[~idx_regions,'region'] = None
# fill up missing regions
df['region'] = df['region'].ffill()

# Drop superfluous rows.
df = df.loc[df['variety'] != df['region']]
```

Be aware that this drops some entries from your original df, i.e. cells [0,1] and [3,1]